# How to handle Customer satisfaction scores with inexperience as missing values?

Tags: regression, data-science, data-analysis, missing-data

I am working on this school project in R program where I am trying to find the most impactful touchpoint(from their satisfaction scores) for increasing NPS(promoter, neutral and detractor). Here I have multiple touch point(almost 8) with satisfaction scores ranging from 1 to 5(highly unsatisfied to highly satisfied). Since not all the people have experienced all the touch point(mostly 2 or 3 touch point per person is seen), there are many missing values in the satisfaction scores. I am not sure how to handle these missing values and what would be the best way to perform this regression. Since missing values indicates inexperience imputing 0 or other values also doesn't seem correct to me. I would really appreciate if anyone of you could help me with this.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is rather implementation centered...for more general statistical advice there is https://stats.stackexchange.com/